# How can I identify my custom plugin to Gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I developed a custom Gradle `<Project>` Plugin for some functionality I needed. It's a plugin because I don't want to clutter my `build.gradle` with the code. It's specific to just one project so I wasn't interested in publishing or sharing it. I want the plugin to live locally (only) in my project's `buildSrc` directory hierarchy and be called from there.

Now, although I followed all the conventions, there's no way to get the plugin applied because it's never found.

```
Plugin [id: 'com.smotricz.myPlugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

My Plugin is a class so it (of course) has a qualified class name. But Gradle, in its plugin syntax, asks for an ID, which isn't the same. Would specifying the "correct" ID for my plugin make it accessible? How can I discover or attach an ID to my plugin's code?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the solutions (I've found 2) aren't in either of the (otherwise great) Gradle books I own.

## Solution 1

I discovered this one very hidden away in [Gradle's online docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#behind_the_scenes):

> ### Behind the scenes
>
> So how does Gradle find the Plugin implementation? The answer is - you
> need to provide a properties file in the JAR’s META-INF/gradle-plugins
> directory that matches the id of your plugin, which is handled by Java
> Gradle Plugin Development Plugin.
>
> ### Example: Wiring for a custom plugin
>
> Given a plugin with ID `org.example.greeting` and implementation class
> `org.example.GreetingPlugin`:
>
> > **`src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/org.example.greeting.properties`**
> >
> > `implementation-class=org.example.GreetingPlugin`
>
> Notice that the properties filename matches the plugin id and is
> placed in the resources folder, and that the implementation-class
> property identifies the Plugin implementation class.

I followed this advice, creating a `myPlugin.properties` file specifying my implementation class (`com.smotricz.MyPlugin`), and was then able to apply my plugin in the usual way in my project's `build.gradle` :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.9.0' // unrelated
    id 'myPlugin'
}
```

...and I can now access the `Task`s and `Action`s from that plugin in my `build.gradle`.

## Solution 2

I discovered this while fact-checking for this answer. Maybe it's not necessary to create the META-INF file after all if you code the link into `buildSrc/build.gradle`. This again comes from [Gradle's online documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html):

> ### Applying plugins from the buildSrc directory
>
> You can apply plugins that reside in a project’s buildSrc directory as
> long as they have a defined ID. The following example shows how to tie
> a plugin implementation class — `my.MyPlugin` — defined in `buildSrc` to
> the ID "`my-plugin`":
>
> **Example 4. Defining a buildSrc plugin with an ID**
>
> `buildSrc/build.gradle`
>
> ```
> plugins {
>     id 'java-gradle-plugin' 
> }
>
> gradlePlugin {
>     plugins {
>         myPlugins {
>             id = 'my-plugin'
>             implementationClass = 'my.MyPlugin'
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

UPDATE: I tried this ("Solution 2") on 2023-10-25 but couldn't get it to work. So I'm sticking with Solution 1.